Azure silently drops http response after 5 minutes
I have a public test-web server that returns http response after 10 minutes (Pretending to do some work for 10 minutes). Then I have a simple Powershell script that sends a GET message to the web server as below.
Get-date
Invoke-WebRequest "https://xxx/home/timeout" -TimeoutSec 5000
Get-Date

When I run the script from my local computer or another public server I tested with, I simply get a response after 10 minutes as I should.
When I run the script from any VM in Azure (Have tried several machines in different tenants), I do not get a response at all! Not even a "Session has been terminated", or any error. It is like Azure is silently dropping my return response. The problem starts when the response takes more than 5 minutes.. Below 5 minutes, it works.
I have tried changing the Idle timeout value on the public IP-address, but no luck.

Any idéas? I have also raised a ticket with Azure support.
The actual case is much more complicated, but the problem has been isolated and simplified to the above issue.

Microsoft states that a four minute idle timeout exists for the firewall. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/firewall/firewall-faq#how-does-azure-firewall-handle-idle-timeouts

In addition to the load balancer.

@GregAskew Good to know, but if the firewall would terminate the connection (With TCP RST as statet in the link), then I would get notified at the client side that the connection has been terminated. The issue also comes after 5 minutes.
